# How to fix boot failure after update

Tags: linux, debian, apt, upgrade

I did a `apt-get update` on Debian. After reboot the system lost its mount point and failed to boot.

How could be accomplished to fix the boot failure?

Comment: Don't you mean upgrade instead of update?

Comment: no it's update..

Comment: Then you'll need to give us more information. The `apt-get update` command will not install/uninstall or otherwise affect the files on your system, it just refreshes the database of available packages. You must have done something else.

Comment: @terdon if it updates the kernel or grub itself, then it does affect the boot mechanism.

Comment: @bersch `apt-get UPGRADE` might, not `apt-get update` which does not make any changes apart from refreshing the package lists available at the repositories.

Comment: Ahh, that's right. I meant upgrade, so it should be also fixed in the question.